# SQL Spark - Lag vs first row by Group

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I'm SQL newbie and I'm trying to calculate difference between the averages.
I want for each item and year calculate difference between months, but I want always substract current average - fist month of this year/item. 
So for example, Item A, 2020, month =3 will have output = 0.6 because 3.7 - 3.1 (as this is the value for first month of this item) - is this correct approach? or maybe lag fuction is the wrong solution?

So far I was trying this one, but it calculates the difference vs previous row instead always using first month row.

```
SELECT item, 
       year, 
       month,  
       average,
       average - COALESCE(LAG(average,1) OVER(
           PARTITION BY item
           ORDER BY year,`month` ),`average`)
AS difference FROM xxx
```

TABLE:

```
+------+------+-------+---------+--------+
| item | year | month | average | wanted OUTPUT |
+------+------+-------+---------+--------+
| a    | 2020 | 1     | 3.1     | 0      |
+------+------+-------+---------+--------+
| a    | 2020 | 2     | 3.5     | 0.4    |
+------+------+-------+---------+--------+
| a    | 2020 | 3     | 3.7     | 0.6    |
+------+------+-------+---------+--------+
| a    | 2020 | 4     | 4.1     | 1.0    |
+------+------+-------+---------+--------+
| b    | 2020 | 1     | 2.0     | 0      |
+------+------+-------+---------+--------+
| b    | 2020 | 2     | 2.1     | 0.1    |
+------+------+-------+---------+--------+
| b    | 2020 | 3     | 2.5     | 0.5    |
+------+------+-------+---------+--------+
| b    | 2020 | 4     | 4.0     | 2.0    |
+------+------+-------+---------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you want window function `FIRST_VALUE()` instead of `LAG()`:

```
SELECT item, 
       year, 
       month,  
       average,
       average - FIRST_VALUE(average) OVER(PARTITION BY item, year ORDER BY month) AS difference 
FROM xxx
```

This compares the `average` of each row against the value of the first `month` of the same `item` and `year`.